# cache drivers configuration

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am currently using Symfony with multiple entity managers. I did this accordingly to their [example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html).
Everything works fine in dev and test environment. The connections are established and I can fetch, insert, etc my data as I want to. But then I came accross the problem that I seem to can't establish any connection to my databases in my prod environment: When I try to login it prints some standard error message like "You can not login because of some system problem". So I checked the logs: nothing. Maybe I need to adjust my verbosity level in prod? I couldn't find a way to get some kind of actual error message. Due to this reason I started comparing the configurations for the different environments. And there is a difference for doctrine on those three environments: test and dev don't use any file to overwrite some settings specified in the default doctrine configuration file. Prod does. And because I changed much stuff in my doctrine configuration file it seemed plausible that problem is burried right there. I deleted the additional doctrine configuration file for prod environment and it worked as expected again.

Here is my standard doctrine configuration file (dontrine.yaml):

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
    # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
    # environment variables are not available yet.
    # You should not need to change this value.
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: admin
        connections:
            admin:
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                url: '%env(DB_ADMIN_URL)%'
                charset:  utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
            mail:
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                url: '%env(DB_MAIL_URL)%'
                charset:  utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
            host:
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                url: '%env(DB_HOST_URL)%'
                charset:  utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: admin
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        entity_managers:
            admin:
                connection: admin
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    Admin:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Admin'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Admin'
                        alias: Admin
            mail:
                connection: mail
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                mappings:
                    Mail:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Mail'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Mail'
                        alias: Mail
            host:
                connection: host
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                mappings:
                    Host:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Host'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Host'
                        alias: Host
```

This is my additional doctrine.yaml for prod environment:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.system_cache_provider
        query_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.system_cache_provider
        result_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.result_cache_provider

services:
    doctrine.result_cache_provider:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.result_cache_pool'
    doctrine.system_cache_provider:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.system_cache_pool'

framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.app
            doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.system
```

The configuration file for prod environment corresponds to the default one. I tried to add all these additional configurations once per entity manager as I did in the default configuration (for my multiple databases). But I didn't work. I don't actually know what this configuration is responsible for but I guess there is a reason why it has been added to default prod environment. I don't just want to delete it.

My questions are now:

- How do I extend the additional configuration properly?
- What is the sense in this configuration?